# perl regex match and store specific character in scalar variable

Tags: regex, perl

Now suppose say i have this line in a file:

```
my %address = (
```

or any such similar line in which i have defined the hash.

I want to find the character "(" in the line and store "address" in say $hash_name. How do I do it?

Basic idea is to capture the name of the hash defined in the files.

I am trying to do is,

```
foreach $line <MYFILE> {
  if($line =~ /($/ {
```

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Is this the only hash name you expect to grep, or there could be a number of them? As a sidenote, how about using [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/module/PadWalker) instead?

Comment: It is just an example that i have quoted here. It can be anything.. But the character "(" is a definite thing that i am looking for in the line and that is when i want to capture the "hash name"

Comment: Have you considered using `PPI`?

Comment: Do you want to learn how to use regular expressions or do you want to parse perl?

Comment: @Zaid - I am not aware of PPIs

Comment: @dgw - I want to know how to do the above specific thing that i have asked.

Comment: @raina77ow - I don't think PadWalker will help me in this.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/module/PPI

Comment: Is [this](http://codepad.org/BxKNI7xF) what you want?

Comment: the parenthesis and the dollar signs are meta-char.. you need to encode it `/\(\$/`

Comment: This question implies that you are attempting a very fragile solution to some unknown problem. Parsing source code in a language that has as its motto *"There is more than one way to do it"* is masochistic at best. Why not mention what it is you are trying to accomplish by extracting hash names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem, but, how about:

```
my %hash;
while (my $line = <MYFILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /\%(\w+)\s*=\s*\($/) {
        $hash{$1} = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it storing the hash name? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @VinodRM: `$1` contains `address` in your example. Then we create an entry in the hash `%hash` with the key `address` and put `1` as value.

Comment: @M42: It would be nice if your code even came close to compiling. There are numerous parentheses, a brace and an equals sign missing.

Comment: @Borodin: You're right, corrected. I've just taken OP's code without inspect it carefuly.

Comment: @M42: Close! `while (my $line = <MYFILE>) { ... }` and an extra closing brace.

Answer (score -2):

```
open (F1,"inputfile.txt") or die("unable to open inputfile.txt");
my $hash_name
    while (<F1>) {
        if (/%(\w+) *= *\(/) {
            $hash_name = $1;
            print $hash_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for making some corrections. Still: if open fails, you need to include `$!` in the error; `$hash_name` should be declared as a lexical variable using `my`;